# how to delete a single semicolon separated value from database in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, sql-delete

My Database table is like below, table name is `add_family` :

```
id    ,   Head_id   ,Head_Name   , CustomerName    customer_id                   
1     ,   2589      ,   Mitesh   ,  anuj^anil   ,  456^259  
2     ,    2590     ,  vijay     ,  amit^ajay   ,  852^454
```

if I want to delete any of customer name and its id then how can I delete it in CodeIgniter? e.g if I want to delete only `CustomerName` Anuj and his `customer_id` 456 where `Head_id` is 2586,

how can I delete it?

Comment: not deleted you should update it

Answer (score -1):

What you should do is use query builder class and load database library.

Here's an example from official [docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#updating-data):

```
$data = array(
        'CustomerName' => 'anil',//or NULL if you want to 'delete it'
        'customer_id' => '259'//or NULL if you want to 'delete it'
);

$this->db->where('Head_id', 2586);
$this->db->update('add_family', $data);
```

If you want to do it dynamically and you always want the part after the `^` you can use , for example, the [php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) `explode` function like this:

```
$this->db->select('CustomerName, customer_id');
$this->db->where('Head_id', 2586); 
$query = $this->db->get('add_family');
$result = $query->row_array(); 

$data = array(
            'CustomerName' => explode('^', $result['CustomerName'])[1],
            'customer_id' => explode('^', $result['customer_id'])[1]
    );

$this->db->where('Head_id', 2586);
$this->db->update('add_family', $data);
```

Note that you should not update the ID of a table if it's the primary key.

Answer (score -3):

Try something like this. Idea is that to get value from database of both field and replace customer name with empty string

```
$query = $this->db->get_where('add_family',array('id'=>1));
$name = str_replace("anuj","", $query['CustomerName']);
$id = str_replace(456, "", $query['customer_id ']);

$data = array(
        'CustomerName' => $name,//or NULL
        'customer_id' => $id//or NULL
);

$this->db->where('Head_id', 2586);
$this->db->update('add_family', $data);
```